# Source a virtual environment using python

Tags: python, subprocess, virtual-environment

On the servers I am working on, there is a virtual environment which can be activated using `source /bin/virtualenv-activate`. I need this virtual environment because of a command line tool which is accessible only there. Let's call it `fancytool`. What I would like to do is to use `fancytool` out of a python script and return its output into a python variable. The python script is not initiated in the virtual environment, so I thought of something like this:

```
os.system('source /bin/virtualenv-activate')
results = os.popen(fancytool).read()
```

However, this returns:

```
sh: 1: source: not found
sh: 1: fancytool: not found
```

If I enter `source /bin/virtualenv-activate` in the terminal and then `fancytool`, everything works fine. How can I achieve this also in a python script?

Comment: Why not just clone the virtual environment and then build your script in it?

Comment: The script is called from within another script which cannot be called in the virtual environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a shebang to the top of the script to activate the env

```
#!/path/to/venv/bin/python 

# your code here
```

However relying on the knowledge of the venv within your scripts is considered poor practice

Comment: I tried it. It still returns the error ```sh: 1: fancytool: not found```. Note that ```fancytool``` is from another software than python inside the virtual environment. The virtual environment is not a python virtualenv

Comment: Well, to me that says your PATH doesn't have said command on it. Try using the full path to the executable

Comment: I do use the full path, e.g. ```#!/bin/virtualenv/python```

Comment: No. To fancy tool

Comment: yes, it does work! But what would be the 'good practice' then?

Comment: The python script itself should have no reference to a virtual environment. You should provide an external config file that allows you to load which path that `fancytool` binary exists in